# Extract unique values from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out how to extract the unique car numbers from 3 seperate sets of tables.  The criteria is as follows...

1. Sheet A has 2 columns; Column A has a list of car numbers and Column B shows the car status as "active" and "inactive".  I need to extract the "active" cars and ignore the "inactive" cars.
2. Sheets B and C have a list of car numbers from 2 different brokers.

I would like a way extract the individual car numbers from each sheet and display them in Sheet D with other data as well.

I've found a way to do it in multiple steps but not in one clean formula.

Comment: A formula that retrieves a unique list from a single column on sheet A will error when it runs out of unique items to retrieve. Wrap one of those in an IFERROR that has a similar formula that retrieves further unique items from sheet B's column. Wrap all of that in another IFERROR that retrieves even more unique items from sheet C's column.

Comment: btw, do you have the newer [Unique function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) in your version of Excel?

Comment: In Sheet D,, are you need unique IDs and related records from Sheet A to C ? Are Sheet B & C are identical ? Better [Edit] your post & add sample data.

Comment: Jeeped... I don't seem to have the Unique function.  We use Office 365 but i guess that isn't included in this version of Excel.

Comment: Rajesh... thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try to get it modified next week.  I'm basically needing to search 3 Sheets for unique VIN numbers for vehicles from 3 different sources.  In sheet A is our primary list of vehicles.  On sheets B and C are lists of vehicles currently listed with 2 of our brokers.  I basically need to monitor these lists and make sure all active vehicles are listed with our brokers.

Answer (score 1):

A formula that retrieves a unique list from a single column on sheet A will error when it runs out of unique items to retrieve. Wrap one of those in an IFERROR that passes processing to a similar formula which retrieves further unique items from sheet B's column A. Wrap all of that in another IFERROR that retrieves even more unique items from sheet C's column A.

Finally, wrap the whole kaboodle in one more IFERROR that returns a zero-length-string rather than #N/A errors for when you finally run out of unique values to retrieve.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(
    INDEX(Aa!A$2:A$99, MATCH(0, IF(Aa!B$2:B$99="active", COUNTIF(A$1:A1, Aa!A$2:A$99), 1), 0)),
    INDEX(Bb!A$2:A$99, MATCH(0, IF(Bb!B$2:B$99="active", COUNTIF(A$1:A1, Bb!A$2:A$99), 1), 0))),
    INDEX(Cc!A$2:A$99, MATCH(0, IF(Cc!B$2:B$99="active", COUNTIF(A$1:A1, Cc!A$2:A$99), 1), 0))), "")
```

[image]

Comment: It's the simplest method,, but will work properly,, +10 ☺

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate the help.  I'm having to teach myself a lot of stuff for Excel and Access for work.  Sites like this help a lot.